# How do I exclude files/folders from a .NET Core/Standard project?

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

In .NET Core and .NET Standard projects, if you put files and folders within the project directory, they are automatically picked up by Visual Studio; essentially they are part of the project.

What if I have files/folders in there that aren't really part of the project itself (in terms of code or content) - short of removing them altogether, is there a way I can exclude them from the project as I can with projects targeting the full .NET Framework?

Comment: You can set the `CopyToOutputFolder` property for each file to `Never`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Open the project in Visual Studio, and right click the files and folders in Solution Explorer. Choose `Exclude from Project`.

That's exactly what you do for projects targeting .NET Framework.

Comment: Try to do that with folder that contains 17k+ subdirectories of user uploads, it will never complete

Comment: that is not an option when I right click using VS2019.  Is there are work around for something more current, (as if 19 is current now)

Comment: @AggieJonof87 Check the other answers. They showed you how to edit the project file instead.

Answer (score 123):

There are also a few things you can do in the csproj files to make sure the files aren't picked up:

1) Make sure none of the globbing patterns that look for "project items" pick up the files:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);your_nonproj.file;a\**\*.pattern</DefaultItemExcludes>
</PropertyGroup>
```

2) Remove items explicitly:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="hidden.file" />
  <Content Remove="wwwroot\lib\**\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note that, on large directories (number of files), using DefaultItemExcludes with the `folder\**` pattern is a lot faster since msbuild will skip walking the directory entirely. Using a remove for this will still let msbuild spend quite some time discovering files.

Comment: is there any problem using below as default and use include information for every included file. any performance impact?
 <DefaultItemExcludes>**;$(DefaultItemExcludes)</DefaultItemExcludes>

Comment: On large directories (number of files), using `DefaultItemExcludes` with a `the\folder\**` pattern is a lot faster since msbuild will skip walking the directory entirely. using a remove for this will still let msbuild spend quite some time discovering files.

Comment: I had to use `<Compile Remove="otherproject\**\*" />` to get it to build when we had one project in the subfolder of another.

Answer (score 39):

Just to be complete, if you're using `ItemGroup` to exclude folder, then:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Remove="excluded_folder\**" />
  <Compile Remove="excluded_folder\**" />
  <EmbeddedResource Remove="excluded_folder\**" />
  <None Remove="excluded_folder\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Because, I had an angular project with the `node_modules` folder which had very long paths and VS kept throwing exceptions. And using `<Content Remove="node_modules\**\*" />` didn't work.

Comment: As stated by @MartinUllrich, it's better to use <DefaultItemExcludes> (_especially_ for `node_modules`) because it will prevent the compiler from even looking in those directories, which will significantly reduce build times (in the case of `node_modules`).

Comment: The config I posted does the same thing. `<Compile Remove="excluded_folder\**" />` **prevents the compiler from even looking in those directories**

Comment: Actually, I believe you're mistaken about that and it's not the same thing. As, again stated by @MartinUllrich, "using a remove for this will still let msbuild spend quite some time discovering files".  Using `Remove` like you have here might prevent VS from throwing errors at you, but it's still affecting your build times.  Also, you left out `Content`, so if there are "content" files in that excluded_folder, they would still be included.  Another win for `<DefaultItemExcludes>`, IMO, since you just have to specify the exclude glob once instead of for each item type like you have shown.

Comment: Also, I want to be clear that I'm not saying you should _never_ use `Remove`.  Obviously, they are both useful.  All I'm saying is that, in the case of excluding files/folder that never have any business being in a build (such as `node_modules`), `Remove` is not the right tool for the job and it's better to use `DefaultItemExcludes`.

Comment: @Sensei_Shoh The reason I like this answer is that I can't seem to get my dotnet5 database <Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj/1.16.2"> to honor <DefaultItemExcludes> at all, so I have to do it this way.

Answer (score 13):

In case you want to **exclude files from the compilation process** but still **have them in the solution explorer tree**, then

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Templates\**" />
    <Content Include="Templates\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Templates are the folder name (in this case) and everything inside it will be ignored by compiler but included in VS

Answer (score -2):

The only option I have found to ever work is to exclude from project, unfortunately.