# Visual Studio 2017 Vue: Only one tag allowed at root level

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js

I've forked a .NET Core project with Vue and opened it in Visual Studio 2017, and downloaded the extension "Vue.js Pack 2017".

However, after opening the Vue components, I find a lot of syntax errors. It appears Visual Studio tries to parse them as XML?

Example of errors:

`Character '@', hexidemical value 0x40 is illegal in an XML Name.`

`Namespace prefix ':' is not defined.`

`XML document cannot contain multiple root level elements.`

`Only one tag allowed at root level`

Definitely seems related to XML parsing - how do I disable checking for that inside `.Vue` files?

Comment: I wonder how is this related to [tag:c#] for you to include that tag?

Comment: It is a .NET Core project; I wouldn't know if it's related to config files or project setup for that or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I exclude files/folders from a .NET Core/Standard project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173811/how-do-i-exclude-files-folders-from-a-net-core-standard-project)