# How can I exclude `Settings.Designer.cs` from `netstandard` builds?

Tags: .net, .net-standard, csproj

I've got an old-style `Settings` class in my project, but I'm trying to convert to `netstandard2.0` and I'd like to drop that option while being backwards-compatible and including it on `net45` builds.

I've figured out how to exclude the constructor where I'm using it, but I also have to remove it from the build using the `.csproj`.

My `.cs`:

```
public class Client
{
    #if !NETSTANDARD2_0
    public Client(Settings settings) { this.url = settings.Url }
    #endif
}
```

My `.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net45</TargetFrameworks>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs" Condition="" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173811/how-do-i-exclude-files-folders-from-a-net-core-standard-project Use the new syntax to exclude that file, and add a condition to test `Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'!='net45'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude them via a pattern:

```
<Compile Remove="**\*.Designer.cs" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net45'" />
```