# Stop Visual Studio 2019 from automatically adding files in project folder

Tags: visual-studio-2019, projects-and-solutions

I have a .NET Core 3 project in Visual Studio 2019. When I copy and paste a file, through Windows Explorer, into the project folder, Visual Studio automatically includes the file into my project, which I do not want to happen. Is there a setting to disable this feature?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Visual Studio, why are all files automatically part of my C# project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479345/in-visual-studio-why-are-all-files-automatically-part-of-my-c-sharp-project)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting from VS 2017 project format in .NET has changed. You need to add <PropertyGroup> tag at the top of your .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup> 
    <EnableDefaultItems>false</EnableDefaultItems>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Here is the complete answer to your question:
[In Visual Studio, why are all files automatically part of my C# project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479345/in-visual-studio-why-are-all-files-automatically-part-of-my-c-sharp-project)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can modify the known project file (.csproj for c# project), by customize the items include path that satisfied your include files specifically.

For more details, you can check these out:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-well-known-item-metadata?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN

[Understanding a csproj assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578819/understanding-a-csproj-assembly-reference)

[Including content files in .csproj that are outside the project cone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292351/including-content-files-in-csproj-that-are-outside-the-project-cone)

Enjoy and deploy with confidence!