# Visual studio 2019 .netcore Load entire dependency tree of project

Tags: c#, architecture, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.1

Lets take the following classical architecture : (vs 2019 net core 3.1)

- One project (A) with Interfaces
- One project (B) with Implementations
- One project (C) that make the mapping with interfaces and implementations.
- One WebSite or consoleApp (D) that reference C and A

In the code of D i can use concrete class of B without build problem even if i dont reference the project. The reference of C bring automatically the B.

I found this thread : [In Visual Studio, why are all files automatically part of my C# project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479345/in-visual-studio-why-are-all-files-automatically-part-of-my-c-sharp-project) apparently it's a new feature and it would make things easier. But none of the solution works for me.

How can i removed this strange behavior ? If want to be forced to use Interfaces and have a build error if i use implementations in D.

When i right click on my project there is two things : "Load direct dependencies of project" and "Load entire dependency tree of project" this appears to be the solution, but it only open my .csproj in edition...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to edit csproj of C project and update :

```
<PackageReference Include="B" Version="X.X.X" />
```

by

```
<PackageReference Include="B" Version="X.X.X">
   <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Microsoft reference :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha#controlling-dependency-assets

Comment: Hi, @Eric Gontier. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.