VS2022 IDE Bug? Adding a unit test project to an existing solution is also adding duplicate files to the existing project
Not sure what is causing this odd behavior:
Step1: I had a project, one solution , one project.
C:\Repos\CatWeather

So CatWeather.csproj and CatWeather.csproj are in this folder.
Builds fine. OK.
Now I right click on the solution and choose to Add A New Project, a Unit Test project.
Well I do want them to be under same source control branch so I choose the location of this one to be inside the same folder

And that's where it gets messed up. Look at what it does:


This is wrong and causes build to fail. Even if I delete that extra folder, it keep building it and putting it back. Why is it doing that?

Seems like some build configuration, Maybe there something messed up in project properties? I would also try analyze *.sln file and *.csproj file to see if there are any unexpected issues (compare with the other project that is correctly set). Also, you could try recreating the project.

@MichałTurczyn compared now. Nothing out of ordinary. A good sample project the only different as that's older and .NET 6.0 but build , config, etc were the same which are both pretty much the defaults you get by wizard building the apps.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173811/how-do-i-exclude-files-folders-from-a-net-core-standard-project

Does the problem happen in new project or latest Visual Studio?

@MinxinYu-MSFT yes, latest VS Professional and brand new projects. The "exclude" solution that was suggested in the link above from Hans solved the problem.
